What happened to good old fashioned spray-on negative-acting photoresist?
Years ago, while taking a graphic arts course in college, I shot negatives of some printed circuit art (hand-drawn, optimized for broad traces and minimal etchant depletion, and ganged with a class project to avoid wasting film).
At the time, Radio Shack still sold negative-acting photoresist, in a spray can, and I made maybe as many as half a dozen of them (using a simple contact frame under direct sunlight for exposure).
I expect to actually need a bunch of the boards I designed (essentially dirt-cheap signal logic for model trains, on a 2-inch square card, based on 2N2222 transistors), before too much longer.
Looking around online, I find that 2N2222s are not only still readily available, but dirt-cheap. Single-sided PCB stock, and ferric chloride solution, also appear to be readily available.
But I also found that negative-acting photoresist spray seems to have fallen into a black hole.
Any suggestions?
All I see is some sort of adhesive film, on Amazon, with mixed reviews. I admit that the idea of washing soda as a developer (instead of the strong organic solvent that the Radio Shack spray used) is attractive, but some of the negative comments complain about very limited documentation, and the need to heat-set the film before exposure and etching. Anybody have any experience with that stuff?
Or would I be able to get decent results if I scanned my negatives, and then laser printed them onto the toner transfer sheets I've also seen on Amazon?
For that matter, given that I spend my Saturdays docenting at a printing museum, I could probably cut a stencil from my negatives, and silk-screen the trace pattern onto boards, for less than it would cost to convert my art to Gerber format (probably ruining the etchant-optimizations in the process).
But does anybody here have any experience with either the blue plastic photoresist film I've seen on Amazon, or with toner transfer sheets?

What happened was that board fabs got cheap enough to make home fab no longer worth it for most applications. That and RadioShack can no longer gouge your eyes out with 0.1uF ceramic caps for $0.75 each when you can go online and buy 100 for the same price so they stopped catering to electrical hobbyists and now they just sell...RC cars?

How cheap? For a bunch of single-sided cards, 2 inches square, same hand-drawn art as in my original post?

Those places only accept gerbers but you could get them for as low as $1.50 per square inch, so $6 each. Depending on your definition of "a bunch" you could probably go even lower.

Saw the part about Gerber files at one online PCB house, but I haven't a clue what a Gerber file is. I'd also be open to toner transfer (if it's really any good), or to seeing if a photoengraver friend of mine would be able to do something with my negatives.

@JamesH.H.Lampert vector art, like SVG or EPS, but specific to PCB manufacture.

Gerber files are produced by PCB layout programs such as KiCAD.  The Gerber files are used to produce the artwork necessary to etch your PC boards.

I figured it was something like that. At any rate, at around $6 to have boards made from a format I have no access to, is about six times what it would cost me to etch my own. So that brings us back to the original question

You can get copper clad board precoated with photoresist, though usually positive acting rather than negative.

Along with products like Kontakt POSITIV 20 (spray on positive photo resist)

Are we assuming that drilling holes also has a labor cost of $0? My first circuit board ever was done with toner transfer using a clothing iron and it was a miserable experience. You sound like you’re cool with dealing with harsh chemicals so you should try it yourself and see how it goes. Might slso want to grab a bottle of “Liquid Tin” so you can plate the exposed copper. My calculations for getting ready-made 2in x 2in boards from China are closer to $0.50 per board (shipped) so it might be worth it to figure out a way to get your art into the proper format.

Drilling holes? Let's see: two transistors (both of which are the venerable, and dirt-cheap, 2N2222) and six resistors (I'm used to half-watt, so I designed the board around them). Total of 18 holes. No ICs, so no tight tolerances. Probably no more than 2 minutes of drill press time per board. :-)

This is not an answer about spray resist but it’s too long for a comment.
You are a graphic artist with a sense of adventure so it may be something worth trying. Nothing to lose, etc.
Moreover you will be avoiding c21 culture of “just press the magic button and don’t try to understand”.

With plenty of Cu on the one hand and FeCl_3 on the other, you can afford to experiment.
Try kinds of black enamel paint and see if you can find one which protects the copper from the etchant.
(Why black? So you can see it.)
Get a paintbrush and paint your circuit.
Etch.


Sharpie ink does a good job of resisting ferric chloride in my experience.  Just get a big fat-tip pen if you need to cover large areas.  "Sharpie Magnum" would be worth a try.  Comes off with IPA and a soft sponge.

What is "c21 culture"?

"IPA": I'm assuming you mean isopropanol, not Irish pale ale. :-P  And if I were to cut a stencil and silk-screen the boards, I'm sure I'd be able to find something that would block ferric chloride (relatively innocuous, compared to, say, nitric acid), but still be easily stripped. Oh, and "graphic artist" is "fightin' words" to me: a term for people who've taken fine arts graphic design classes, but who have never picked up a composing stick in their lives. :-P

And I'm guessing that the "c21 culture" to which Mr. Kochanski is referring is today's culture of not bothering to understand how things are made, or how they work, and just throwing money at the problem. Which of course puts one at the mercy of one's vendor. In short, the precise opposite of "maker" and "open source" culture.

Sounds like you want to do things your own way, which don't let me stand in your way, but I'll point out that you are currently at the mercy of the vendor(s) of negative-acting spray on photoresist.

Actually, it would seem that I'm no longer at the mercy of negative-acting-photoresist-spray vendors: there apparently aren't any left. At any rate, I've got some toner transfer paper on its way from Amazon, to see if they work.  Cheap, and worth a try, since it's easy enough to either scan my negatives, or scan some contact prints I'd made, the last time I had photographic paper and some Dektol that hadn't gone rancid, or maybe the original art, if I still have it.
